# Why does my jinja2 code dont make changes in my html file

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Hi i am trying to make a dynamic web page using jinja2 in python.

This is my python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    title = 'Home'
    return render_template('index.html', title=title)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

And this my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i run the code, the html doesn't change.

Comment: what do you mean by run the code?

Comment: The python code

Comment: yes but how do you run it? how do you verify if it works or not? You must start the server and navigate to / and /about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe the problem lies with your file structure. Click [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/layout/) to read more about flask file structures